# Чи є загальне правило, яке керує написанням "до речі" чи "доречі", "на жаль" чи "нажаль" тощо?

Tags: граматика, правопис, разом-дефіс-окремо, прислівники

Я весь час стикаюся з проблемою написання наступних виразів разом чи окремо:

- *до речі* чи *доречі*?
- *на жаль* чи *нажаль*?
- *на добраніч* чи *надобраніч*?
- *в одночас*, *в одно час* чи *водночас*?

І хоча у словниках дуже легко знайти усі ці слова, іноді словники суперечать одні одним.

Наприклад, СУМ [*річ*](http://sum.in.ua/s/rich) стверджує, що:

> **До речі**: (г) (у значенні вставного слова) уживається для позначення побіжного зауваження, доповнення до щойно висловленого або у зв'язку з ним.
>
> *Хочу себе потішити, що літом буде нам краще і ще заспіваємо з Вами разом у Криворівні. До речі: коли Ви збираєтеся туди?* — Михайло Коцюбинський
>
> *Директор ходив, похитуючись і припадаючи то на одну, то на другу ногу, як моряк, — до речі, він і був колись моряком* — Юрій Яновський

Йому суперечить [словник Грінченка (1958)](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/13461-dorechi.html):

> **Доре́чі** — народне *Кстати*

Я ще чув точку зору, що таке бажання (писати це словосполучення окремо) базується на ідеї штучної підтримки різниці з правилами російської мови ([тут](http://zik.ua/news/2010/11/10/tabachnyk_napysav_slovo_do_rechi_razom_255557) і [тут](http://www.pravda.com.ua/columns/2010/11/11/5560861/) можна почитати про скандал з окупаційним «міністром» освіти, який радив чинити «як у них, так і у нас», а патріотично налаштовані мовознавці пропонували, відповідно, чинити «не так, як у них»).

Отже, питання: **Чи є граматичне (а не політичне) правило, яке може об'єктивно допомогти обрати правопис подібних словосполучень?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Таке правило є, і формулюється воно [таким чином](http://answiki.org.ua/866-yak-pyshetsya-do-rechi.html):

> **Окремо пишуться:**
> Прислівникові сполуки, що складаються з прийменника та іменника, але в яких

> - **іменник** звичайно **зберігає своє конкретне лексичне значення**
> - й граматичну форму,
> - особливо коли між прийменником і керованим ним іменником **можливо вставити означення** до цього іменника (прикметник, займенник, числівник)

Таким чином:

- *до речі* (у значенні "by the way"<sup>англ</sup> або "кстати"<sup>рос</sup>) пишемо **окремо**, тому що:

> *…ще заспіваємо з Вами разом у Криворівні. До **цієї** речі **хочу додати запитання**: коли Ви збираєтеся туди?* — перефразоване із Коцюбинського
> (зауваження: тут, *річ* у значенні «промова», а не «об'єкт»),

- а от *доречний* пишемо **разом**, тому що не існує форми *речний*
- *на жаль* пишемо **окремо**, тому що:

> *на **превеликий** жаль*; *на **мій** жаль*; *на **ваш** жаль*

- *водночас* пишемо **разом**, тому що словоформи *в* та *одно* не поєднуються з іменником *час*, на противагу до словосполучення *в один і той самий час*, яке пишеться **окремо**;
- *нарешті* (у значенні "finally"<sup>англ</sup> або "наконец"<sup>рос</sup>) пишемо разом, тому що лексичне значення *решта* не може бути застосоване тут;

---

Ще одним прикладом групи словосполучень, які **пишуться окремо**, є слова, в яких іменник повторюється — або просто двічі (у Називному та Орудному відмінках), або поєднаний через сполучник:

- *кінець кінцем, один одним*
- *день у день, час від часу, сам на сам*

  - Виняток: *віч-на-віч*

---

Ще існує ціла група словосполучень цієї ж природи, які є калькою з інших мов:

- *так як* — не вживаємо зовсім, використовуємо *оскільки*;
- *такий як* — не вживаємо, правильно — *як-от*;
- [і ще доволі багато](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83_%D0%B7_%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97) подібних слів і словосполучень.

---

## Зауваження.

Мова розвивається. Те, що колись було окремими словами, стало частиною морфології цілісних слів. **Більшість прислівників утворилися за допомогою злиття слів, які раніше мали окремі лексичні значення.**
Цей процес можна простежити, наприклад, по таких словосполученнях, як *добрий день*, яке існує також у формі *добридень*.

Тому, з суто лінгвістичної точки зору, можна припустити, що з часом словосполучення *на жаль* втратять первісну форму, стануть прислівниками і почнуть писатися разом.
А ми з вами наполегливо доводитимемо нашим онукам, що, мовляв, ви, онуки, неправильно пишете *«доречі»* разом, тому що в наші часи писали окремо. :-)

Але на даний момент цього ще не відбулося.

Comment: виправте, будь ласка, оскільки маленьки помилки викликають сумніви щодо великої думки :)
- не наступним чином. наступним у черзі, але таким чином. те саме про слово подібне.
- цей процес можна простежити не по таким словосполученням, а по таких словосполученнях.
- суто лінгвістичної пишеться окремо, а не через дефіс.
- ну і "доводитимемо нашим онукам, що, мовляв, ви, онуки, неправильно пишете": сміливо можна забрати зайву тут кому після що. доводитимемо нашим онукам, що мовляв, ви, онуки, неправильно пишете.
За статтю дякую, згодна з думкою.

Comment: @user5498 дякую за коментар. Перепрошую, що лише зараз помітив його: перетворення відповіді на коментар не викликало появу notification у верхній панелі. Я вніс запропоновані вами правки, окрім останньої: не розумію мотивації прибирати одну з двох ком, які є обов'язковими перед і після вставних слів. Окремо зауважу, що будь-який користувач, незалежно від репутації, має можливість натиснути кнопку Edit і запропонувати правку. У такому випадку notification точно буде, а на додачу інші користувачі можуть approve вашої правки навіть без моєї участі.

Answer (score 1):

["На жаль", пишеться окремо](https://gosta.media/nauka-ta-osvita/iak-pyshetsia-na-zhal-za-novym-pravopysom/), - як два слова. Окреме написання зафіксовано ще в 1929 році – у правописному словнику Голоскевича. Написання "на жаль" базується на структурі – службові частини мови (прийменник) + іменник.

Comment: Дякую. Але, здається, Be Brave Be Like Ukraine питав про загальне правило для всіх подібних випадків, а не суто про «на жаль».