# "Будь ласка" чи "будь-ласка"?

Tags: orthography, разом-дефіс-окремо

В правописі зазначено, що:

> Через дефіс пишуться частки «казна-, хтозна-, **будь-**, небудь, бо-, но-,
>   -то, -от, -таки» (де-небудь, хтозна-який, як-от, пиши-но). Але! **В сполученні «будь ласка», що пишеться окремо, «будь» не є часткою, а
>   окремим словом**.

Проте якщо почитати обговорення цього питання ([один](https://www.facebook.com/uamova/posts/1473998619492400), [два](http://ua-etymology.livejournal.com/225402.html), [три](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/lofiversion/index.php?t1883.html)), то майже в кожному першому обговоренні є люди, які стверджують, що їх вчили писати через дефіс і лише не так давно написання `будь ласка` стало нормою.

Чи дійсно `будь ласка` раніше писалось через дефіс і якщо ні, то звідки/чому з'явилась така поширена помилка?

Comment: Одна із можливих версій — це внаслідок феномену, [описаного тут](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/467/), а саме — частини словосполучення **втратили своє лексичне значення**, «будь» не є дієсловом, і воно не пов'язане відмінком з іменником (?) «ласка». Тобто, якщо безумовно слідувати правилу, то писати треба було б взагалі разом: «будьласка» або, у крайньому випадку, через дефіс.

Comment: @bytebuster Треба ще пошукати в джерелах підтвердження, але точно ніколи не писалось через дефіс. Етимологія - скорочення від "будьте ласкаві". Тому тільки окремо.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, я це і мав на увазі: «будьте ласкаві» — не скорочення, пишемо окремо; «будь ласка», скорочення, пишемо {якось інакше}. Аналогія: «в один і той самий час» — не скорочення, пишемо окремо; «водночас» — скорочення, втрата лексичного змісту, пишемо разом.

Comment: @bytebuster мені здається, в даному випадку відбулося тільки скорочення (без поєднання/складення, як у випадку з "водночас") і без втрати лексичного змісту. Але ж кажу, треба пошукати, що етимологи стверджують.

Comment: доречі хтось шось чув про зникнення м'якого знаку, бо, наприклад, я вимоляю `будласка`, але не певен чи це моя особиста помилка, чи якась тенденція :)

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, з «етимологія — скорочення від „будьте ласкаві“» я категорично не згоден. «Будь ласка» — не скорочення від «будьте ласкаві». Повніша форма — «будь твоя ласка» (наприклад, як «будь моя воля, я би…»).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Словник української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/laska), роки упорядкування **1970-1980**, подає без дефісу й окремо, з посиланням на цитату з "Хіба ревуть воли, як ясла повні?" Панаса Мирного від **1949** року.

> ♦ **Будь ласка**; Коли (як, якщо) [буде] [твоя, ваша і т. ін.] ласка; З
>   ласки вашої (твоєї і т. ін.) — чемне звертання при проханні або згоді
>   на що-небудь. — Збудіть мені, будь ласка, Чіпку (Панас Мирний, I,
>   1949, 278);

Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 4, 1973. — Стор. 449.

Comment: Я б взагалі писав будь_те_ ласка...

Comment: @MikhailT., НМД, це було б неправильно з точки зору походження фрази — або «будь ваша ласка»/«будь твоя ласка» (наприклад, як «будь моя воля, я би…»), або «будьте ласкаві»/«будь ласкавий» — але не суміш.

Answer (score 7):

[Архаїчний приклад з літератури](https://books.google.com.ua/books?ei=BKG9TNvTNo-Cswbb2u3QDQ&ct=result&redir_esc=y&id=CAcOAAAAIAAJ&dq=inauthor%3A%22Ivan%20S.%20Nechu%C4%AD-Levyt%EF%B8%A0s%EF%B8%A1%CA%B9ky%C4%AD%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0): у збірці "Повісті й оповідання" Нечуя-Левицького (1901 рік), надрукованій [ярижкою](http://litopys.org.ua/ukrmova/um149.htm) ***будь ласка*** таки пишеться через дефіс, але погодьтеся, авторитетність досить сумнівна.

Можливо, все почалося з усвідомлення мовцями двох лексем як однієї, можливо - з помилкової аналогії з моделлю творення неозначених займенників та прислівників типу *будь-хто*, *будь-який*, *будь-де*. У цьому випадку "*будь*" виступає часткою і дефіс справді потрібен, але ж фразема "*будь ласка*" походить від словосполучення "будьте ласкаві", тож жодних часток, жодних дефісів і жодних сумнівів не мало б бути.