# «Закордон» чи «за кордон», «закордоном» чи «за кордоном»?

Tags: граматика, правопис, орфографія, spelling, разом-дефіс-окремо

Як треба писати фрази (разом чи окремо)?

> Олег перебуває за кордоном / закордоном.
>   Остап поїхав за кордон / закордон.

<sub>Я вважав, що окремо.

Але мені, посилаючись на [сторінку «Мова. ДНК нації»](//ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu/zakordon-i-za-kordon), пояснюють:

— Тут якраз можна «закордоном», бо маються на увазі зарубіжні країни.

Тобто, виходить, можна обидва варіанти?

І ще потім:

— Є кордон чогось у значенні межа — тоді окремо; а це місце перебування узагальнене — тому й разом.

Тобто, виходить, можна лише разом?

Подивився в корпусі — наче й правда:

— *Вони обидві вже по кілька разів були закордоном, відпочивали з батьками і на Багамах, і в Греції, і в Іспанії…* //[Всеволод Нестайко «Супер „Б“ з „фрикадельками“»](//www.ukrlib.com.ua/books/printit.php?tid=2795&page=6).

— *Так от: або поміщики — тоді їдьмо закордон <…>. Або ж з комедіями раз на завжди покінчить: робити.* //[Володимир Винниченко «Чесність з собою»](//www.ukrlib.com.ua/books/printit.php?tid=2948&page=21).</sub>

То як правильно?

Comment: Related: http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/467/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

На жаль, це поширена помилка. Іноді помиляються навіть найвідоміші письменники. Проте все-таки на одну-дві цитати в корпусі з неправильним написанням припадає багато з правильним, наприклад:

- > Знають за кордоном. //Павло Загребельний «Диво».
- > Всі рвуться за кордон. //Звідти ж.

«Мова. ДНК нації» не помилилася; проте, на жаль, конкретно [цю її сторінку](http://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu/zakordon-i-za-kordon) багато хто інтерпретує неправильно, сприймаючи буквально уривок: «Закордон — іноземні країни, чужі землі, зарубіжжя. За кордон — за межі своєї країни» — і вважаючи, що критерієм вибору між сполученим і відокремленим написанням начебто є зміст, який ми хочемо передати (мовляв, «про закордонні країни — разом, про лінію кордону — окремо»). Це не так.

Насправді обмеженням, що не дає в багатьох випадках писати «за кордон(ом)» разом, є те, що слово «закордон» (у написанні разом) хоча в українській мові й **існує**, але є лише **іменником** (називного або знахідного відмінка, тобто відповідає на питання «що?»), синонімом до слів «**закордоння**» та «**зарубіжжя**», а не прислівником (що відповідає на питання «куди?») — і тому саме лиш воно одне не може виконувати роль обставини місця. А слово «закордоном», відповідно, є тим самим іменником в орудному відмінку (тобто відповідає на питання «чим?») — і теж не може бути обставиною місця (що відповідає на питання «де?»). Як не можна «поїхати зарубіжжя» (лише «у зарубіжжя») — так і не можна «поїхати закордон» (лише «у закордон», або «за кордон»). Як не можна «перебувати зарубіжжям» (лише «у зарубіжжі») — так і не можна «перебувати закордоном» (лише «у закордоні», або «за кордоном»).

[image: Кордон (рубіж) (межа). Закордон (закордоння) (зарубіжжя). «Я поїду за кордон (у закордон)». «Я за кордоном (у закордоні)». «Я приїхав із-за кордону (із закордону)». «Я спілкуюсь із закордоном».]

Answer (score -2):

На жаль повинен не погодитися із відповіддю вище. Потрібно розрізняти прислівники із префіксами і іменники, які мають з прислівником спільний корінь. Одною із головних ознак прислівника є те, що він є **НЕЗМІННОЮ** частиною мови! Отже більшість прикладів із картинки вище (закордону/ом/і) не стосуються прислівника "закордон" узагалі, тому що вони, дійсно, є іменниками. "Закордон" може бути прислівником не зважаючи на те, чи є відповідне слово в іншій частині мови. Такі слова, як "пора", "шкода", "жаль"... залежно від змісту можуть бути як прислівниками, так і іменниками. Дуже мало в українській мові є прислівників розряду місця (відповідають на питання де?, куди? звідки?), які б мали префікс "за". Єдиний приклад, який спадає на думку - "заміж". "Муж" - іменник-> "заміж" - прислівник-> "заміжжя" - знову іменник. Так само  "кордон" - іменник-> "закордон" - прислівник-> "закордоння" - знову іменник. Мова не є набором готових складників, а радше набором правил які допомагають мову творити. Слово "закордон" може бути прислівником тому, що не існує (я не знаю такого) правила, яке б забороняло нам створити такий прислівник.

Comment: В українській мові немає прислівника «закордон». Лише (розмовний) іменник. В тому-то й справа.

Comment: Автори «Мова. ДНК нації» підтримують мою позицію. Можу надати посилання на їхні коментарі в Facebook. Довести свою позицію Ви можете лише одним чином — продемонструвавши (хоча б один) словник, що відмічає «закордон(ом)» як прислівник.

Comment: Тобто, якщо постфактум інтерпретувати вже написане кимось «я поїду закордон», то інакше, ніж, що «закордон» — прислівник, інтерпретувати не вийде. Але річ у тім, що наразі нормами не дозволено так писати (лише «я поїду за кордон»). Може, колись норми послаблять.

Comment: Я б особисто на місці украдачів словників / мовознавців додав би прислівники «закордон» і «закордоном» (адже, як на мене, вони справді звучать і сприймаються, як цілі слова) — але вони пішли шляхом редукціонізму (якщо комбінація прийменника «за» з іменником «кордон» і розмовний іменник «закордон» покривають всі сенси — то нема сенсу додавати ще й прислівники «закордон» і «закордоном»).

Comment: Я вірю, що зараз такого прислівника в українських словниках немає, але жоден словник ні не випереджає, ні навіть не встигає за живою мовою. Ну а мова писана не є тотожною мові розмовній. В українській мові є постфікс "ся", який ми записуємо вкінці слова, в західних діалектах він може стояти окремо перед словом, в інших західних слов'ян  "ся" може писатися завжди окремо. Різниця лиш в традиції написання, яка не є мовою сама по собі. Порівняйте "у горі накопичуються вулканічні гази" і "у_горі летить літак". Значення не зміниться від того, як писати.

Comment: Хочу також додати, що це просто писемна невизначеність. Якщо подивитися, що таке іменник, то серед різних визначень можна буде знайти і питання, на які іменник відповідає - хто?/що?, кого?/чого?..... всі ми їх знаємо. Ніде не написано, що іменник може відповідати на питання де? і куди? І ось тут виникає протиріччя в писемній традиції:  сісти куди? - за стіл(окремо); прийти куди? - додому (разом). Мовознавці десь напартачили.... і то серйозно.

Comment: «У горі» й «угорі» — тут якраз, по-моєму, значення кардинально змінюється. А от кардинальної різниці між «за кордон» і «закордон (прислівник — якби такий існував)» не бачу. Хоча можна припустити, що «за кордон» означає фізичний перетин кордону (навіть на 3 см), а «закордон» — поринання в країни, інші за духом («Білорусь, Росія, Молдова — який же то закордон, то такий самий пост-СРСР, як і в нас; а от Великобританія чи США…»).

Comment: Іменник з прийменником (чи просто в іншому відмідку, ніж називний) цілком може відповідати на питання «де?», «куди?», «звідки?», «коли?» і т.д. (виконуючи роль обставини). Ви ж не кажете, що «в Україну» слід писати разом (хоча воно відповідає на питання «куди?»). А от «додому» — добрий приклад того, як широковживані прийменник з іменником можуть поступово переходити в прислівник навіть без радикальної зміни значення — може, колись таке станеться і з «за кордон(ом)» (чи вже сталося, але просто наші «вчені мужі» не визнають).

Comment: Я маю на увазі що не залежно від того, як ми пишемо "у/горі" ми  розуміємо, що в першому випадку мова йде про гору, а у другому словосполучення є заміною прислівника "високо". (мабуть зрозуміліше було б замість "значення не зміниться..." написати "не має значення").

Comment: Система пропонує переходити в чат... Думаю можна завершувати дискусію, адже ми в основному сходимося у думці. Єдине вверху ви пропонували дати посилання на авторів "ДНК нації", було б цікаво подивитися.

Comment: Так, можна завершувати. Єдине що — хотів сказати, що автоматично зрозуміло, що таке «в( )горі» («високо над нами» чи «всередині якоїсь гори») лише в певних контекстах; в НФ романі, де всередині спорожнених гір облаштовані секретні аеродроми, це вже неоднозначність. Вибаче, на жаль, посилання на коментарі надати не зможу; здається, ту дискусію видалили (це був доволі провокативний адміністратора «И так поймут» з одруком, під яким зав'язалася дискусія про правопис «за( )кордон», в якому з'явилась людина, що представилася як одна із засновників «Мова. ДНК нації» і підтримала мою позицію).