# Переклад слів на кшталт "technics", "robotics"

Tags: переклад, from-english, словотворення

Чому "technics" перекладається як *техніка*, "electronics" як *електроніка*, а "robotics" як *робототехніка*, а не *роботіка*.

Comment: Поки у мові немає зручного шаблону - слово береться з іншої "як є". Якщо шаблон вже існує - нове слово тяжіє до нього. Тим більше що слово "робот" походить від слова "робота", тобто використання засобів слов'янського словотвору цілком виправдане. До того ж, потенційне запозичення (слово "роботика" вигадав Айзек Азімов у 1942 році) відбувалося у часи СРСР, коли всі терміни перекладалися (не "комп'ютер" а "ЕОМ-електронна обчислювальна машина", не "принтер" а "АЦПУ - алфавитно-цифровий друкарський пристрій" і т.і.). Добре що маємо "робототехніку" а не "електронно-механічне конструювання" якесь.

Comment: Мені здається, що це питання трохи не про українську, а про англійську, тобто чому в англійській немає слова _robototechnics_. Немає, бо Айзек Азімов вигадав саме слово _robotics_, а _робототехніка_ – це продукт творчости російськомовних радянських людей.

Comment: Додам, що мало б бути «робо́т**и**ка», а не «робо́т**і**ка», бо [правило дев'ятки](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Правило_дев'ятки).

Answer (score 6):

На мою думку, [коментар](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%82-technics-robotics#comment3898_1455) Yellow Sky якомога точніше позначає проблему.

Не вперше у відповідь на таке запитання проведу порівняльне вікі-дослідження по перекладу цього слова на слов’янські мови:

Болґарська - [Роботика](https://bg.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Хорватська - [Robotika](https://hr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotika)

Польська - [Robotyka](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotyka)

Сербохорватська - [Robotika](https://sh.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotika)

Чеська - [Robotika](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotika)

Словенська - [Robotika](https://sk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotika)

Македонська - [Роботика](https://mk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Я мовчу про мови іврит, арабську, перську, де так саме є "роботика".

Ми тут, як це часто трапляється, у єдиному царстві Російської імперії:

Робототехніку знаходимо у перекладах на [азербайджанську](https://az.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robototexnika), [вірменську](https://hy.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D5%8C%D5%B8%D5%A2%D5%B8%D5%BF%D5%A1%D5%BF%D5%A5%D5%AD%D5%B6%D5%AB%D5%AF%D5%A1), [казаську](https://kk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0), [російську](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0), [чуваську](https://cv.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8) мови. І, звісно, на [українську](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0). [Білоруська](https://translate.google.com/?hl=en#en/be/robotics) на вікіпедії не знаходиться, але ґуґл-перекладач, здається, знає, як переклали й там.

[Етимолоґія](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotics#Etymology):

Беручи до уваги те, що слово *робот* уперше застосував Карл Чапек у своєму романі "Р.У.Р", а слово *роботика* — Айзек Азімов у повісті "Брехун!" (дякую Artemix за [коментар](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%82-technics-robotics/2707#comment3887_1455)), ми мали б просто транслітерувати це слово зі споріднених українській слов’янських мов, але, думаю, на той момент такої можливості не було, і змушені були запозичувати через російську.

На сьогодні, вважаю, можна використовувати **роботика**, якщо перед вами не стоїть вимог щодо дотримання чинного правопису або відповідності всіх слів у тексті конкретним словникам.

На рівні назв це вже почали запроваджувати:

> [І це ще не все!.. Організатори активно готують проект-сюрприз, щоб Фестиваль Роботіка став для вас ще видовищнішим.](https://kyiv.dityvmisti.ua/vseukrayinskij-festival-robototehniki-robotica/vseukrayinskij-osvitnij-festival-robototehniki-robotica-2017/)

P.S. У своїй відповіді замінив "роботіка" на "роботика" за [правилом дев'ятки](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8). Також пошукав "роботику" замість "роботіки" в ґуґлі й знайшов цілих [665 результатів](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%22&source=lnt&tbs=lr:lang_1uk&lr=lang_uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwv8GK_OvgAhVO_SoKHUG4DiwQpwUIJQ&biw=1366&bih=657) з посиланнями на навчання [за кордоном](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/900/240), всеукраїнські олімпіади, [переклади книг](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=2n51DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT566&lpg=PT566&dq=%22%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%22&source=bl&ots=cPHJuJr9Fv&sig=ACfU3U2_Y3Ue71c9qLmX1_e033lAy6Nm4A&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmkcrT_OvgAhULp4sKHeoaB9M4ChDoATACegQIBhAB#v=onepage&q=%22%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%22&f=false) тощо. Отже, вже маємо набагато більше підстав вживати слово "роботика".